# how to make it more responsive this page specially on iphone?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>bootstrap</title>
 <style>
  .m-x-3 {margin-right: 3rem !important;margin-left: 3rem !important; }
  .m-y-3 {margin-top: 3rem !important;margin-bottom: 3rem !important; }
  .p-l-3 {padding-left: 3rem !important; }
  .p-r-3 {padding-right: 3rem !important; }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default no-bg b-a-2 b-gray-dark">
        
        <div class="panel-body m-x-3 m-y-3"> 
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                   <p>To:</p>
                  </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
                 <p>Number:</p> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
                   <p>QT-10001</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                        
                        
             <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                 <p>Jefferey Halvorson </p>
                </div>
             <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
                <p>Issue Date:</p>  
                 </div>
               <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
                   <p>15-Mar-2017</p>
                   </div>
                            
                </div>
             </div>
                        
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                  <p>Herzog-Willms </p>
                  </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
               <p> Expiry Date:</p>   
               </div>
             <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
                 <p>15-Mar-2017</p>
                  </div>
                            
                </div></div>
                        
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                   <p>309 Johnson Ford</p>
                 </div>
           <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
               <p>Grand Total:</p>    
              </div>
             <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
          <p>USD 1,469.00</p>
                            </div>
                            
        </div></div>
                        
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <p>Cormiertown, AL 23471-0332</p>
                    </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
                            <p>Status:</p>     
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right">
                             <p>SENT</p>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div></div>

          <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <p>GSTIN: C-66553</p>
                            </div>
                                                       
                        </div></div>
                        
                     </div>
                </div>
      
                    <!-- Table -->
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 p-l-3 p-r-3">
                    
     <table class="table table-condensed">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Item Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>U.O.M</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Total</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>P-203</td>
        <td>HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
        <td>set</td>
        <td>275.00</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1,100.00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>P-203</td>
        <td>HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
        <td>set</td>
        <td>275.00</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1,100.00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>P-203</td>
        <td>HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
        <td>set</td>
        <td>275.00</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1,100.00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>P-203</td>
        <td>HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
        <td>set</td>
        <td>275.00</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1,100.00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>P-203</td>
        <td>HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
        <td>set</td>
        <td>275.00</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1,100.00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="border:0">
        <td style="border:0; text-align:right;">Sub Total:</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="border:0"></td>
        <td style="border:0;text-align:right;">1,100.00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="border:0">
        <td style="border:0; text-align:right;">CGST</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="border:0"></td>
        <td style="border:0;text-align:right;">10,916.00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="border:0">
        <td style="border:0; text-align:right;">SGST</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="border:0"></td>
        <td style="border:0;text-align:right;">28476447</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="border:0">
        <td style="border:0; text-align:right;">Grand Total:</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="border:0"></td>
        <td style="border:0;text-align:right;">USD 10,776.00</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody> 
      <tfoot>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="4" style="border: 0;"><strong>Terms and Conditions:</strong></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="border: 0;">1. Delivery will be made within [DAYS] days following [COMPANY NAME] receipt of payment.</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
      <td colspan="4"style="border: 0;">2. Delivery will be made f.o.b. [COMPANY NAME] facility.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="border: 0;">3. The general terms and conditions of purchase at [WEBSITE LINK OR REFERENCE TO ATTACHMENT]
 apply to this quotation contract.</td>
      </tr>
     </tfoot>
     <!-- END Table -->
                        </table>
                    
                      </div>
                    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- </div> -->
 </div>    
 </div>
</div>

   </body>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have been working on this page from 2 days to make it responsive. Now in chrome i am checking this page responsivess using inspect tools. This page responsiveness is good on all devices except iphone using chrome inspect tools. Now I am confused with this page responsiveness.I used one table element and for content i wrote `bootstrap` columns and rows. I put all these in `panel`.

**Now my question is:** - how to make this page more responded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are using tables, which has a limitation to be adjusted in Mobile Views. Your possible solutions could be :

- Hide Content
- Create horizontal scroll

Both of which are difficult to maintain solutions. So, we need to make adjustments in the layout itself of table itself in Mobile. Here is a solution where in I have changed the structure of table changed using CSS only in mobile to present the data in a more readable form. 
Demo is available at https://jsfiddle.net/8vnkuocb/10/

```
<div class="container">

<table class="table table-condensed" style="padding:20px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>U.O.M</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Item Code">P-203</td>
            <td data-title="Description">HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
            <td data-title="U.O.M">set</td>
            <td data-title="Unit Price">275.00</td>
            <td data-title="Qty">4</td>
            <td data-title="Total">1,100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Item Code">P-203</td>
            <td data-title="Description">HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
            <td data-title="U.O.M">set</td>
            <td data-title="Unit Price">275.00</td>
            <td data-title="Qty">4</td>
            <td data-title="Total">1,100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Item Code">P-203</td>
            <td data-title="Description">HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
            <td data-title="U.O.M">set</td>
            <td data-title="Unit Price">275.00</td>
            <td data-title="Qty">4</td>
            <td data-title="Total">1,100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Item Code">P-203</td>
            <td data-title="Description">HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
            <td data-title="U.O.M">set</td>
            <td data-title="Unit Price">275.00</td>
            <td data-title="Qty">4</td>
            <td data-title="Total">1,100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>P-203</td>
            <td>HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A) HP ENVY 5055 Wireless All-in-One Photo Printer, Instant Ink Ready (M2U85A)</td>
            <td>set</td>
            <td>275.00</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1,100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border:0">
            </td>
            <td style="border:0; text-align:right;">Sub Total:</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border:0"></td>
            <td style="border:0;text-align:right;">1,100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border:0">
            </td>
            <td style="border:0; text-align:right;">CGST</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border:0"></td>
            <td style="border:0;text-align:right;">10,916.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border:0">
            </td>
            <td style="border:0; text-align:right;">SGST</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border:0"></td>
            <td style="border:0;text-align:right;">28476447</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border:0">
            </td>
            <td style="border:0; text-align:right;">Grand Total:</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border:0"></td>
            <td style="border:0;text-align:right;">USD 10,776.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="border: 0;"><strong>Terms and Conditions:</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="border: 0;">1. Delivery will be made within [DAYS] days following [COMPANY NAME] receipt of payment.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="border: 0;">2. Delivery will be made f.o.b. [COMPANY NAME] facility.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="border: 0;">3. The general terms and conditions of purchase at [WEBSITE LINK OR REFERENCE TO ATTACHMENT] apply to this quotation contract.</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <!-- END Table -->
</table>
```

```
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
      table, thead, tbody, th,td,tr {
        display: block;
      }
      .table-condensed {
        border : 0 none;
        thead tr {
          position: absolute;
          top: -9999px;
          left: -9999px;
        }
        tbody tr { 
          border: 1px solid #ccc; 
          td {
            /* Behave like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 25% !important;
            white-space: normal;
            text-align:left;
            &:first-child {
              padding-left:0px;
            }
            &:before {
              /* Now like a table header */
              position: absolute;
              /* Top/left values mimic padding */
              top: 6px;
              left: 6px;
              width: 20%;
              padding-right: 10px;
              white-space: nowrap;
              text-align:left;
              font-weight: 600;
              content: attr(data-title);
            }
            &.sortRowActive {
              background-color: #ddd;
            }
          }
          &.selected-user {
            td {
              background-color: #ffc !important;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Note: Above structure will be applied below 768px (Ipad portrait), you may modify that as per your requirement.

Comment: bro you got me right. i was facing these two problem as you describe(hide content and scroll which my boss don't want.).I will let you know if i faced problem but i think you got solved my problem.tnx

Comment: can i use `<ul></ul>` instead of `<table>` for responsiveness in this scenario?.

Comment: If my understanding is correct what you mean is you will use Table in Ipad and above and UL in Mobile. Answer is yes you can use, but the only disadvantage of using ul would be you will keep duplicate HTML in your code to display data, again maintenance hurdles.